# Laravel timestamps are behind

Tags: php, laravel

When I register a user in my laravel application,
the timestamps are 1 hour behind? So in The Netherlands it's 16.50 and my
timestamps save 15.50.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Is that not because of the server time?

Comment: No that's not the problem. Already checked that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure in your `config/app.php` the following line contains the correct timezone.

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/London',
```

If you change this settings, unfortunately old entries won’t be changed automatically, but new ones will be saved with `created_at`, `updated_at` and similar fields in your specified timezone.

For international projects it could be a good strategy to have all timestamps in `UTC` format and then show the date by user timezone with Carbon. It gives more flexibility now and in the future.

Comment: Thanks but that's not working for me? Still one hour behind.

Comment: Just to be sure: you did that check on a **new** timestamp that was created **after** the timezone change? How did you check your server time?

Comment: @jamie Also, `'Europe/London'` was an example. For Netherlands, it should be `'Europe/Amsterdam'` if you didn't adjust it.